# Salesforce Aura component controller apex test class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test, aura

Having some issues creating a test class for the controller.

```
public without sharing class DeleteFilesCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<FilesWrap> getFiles(string objectId){
        List<FilesWrap> wrapList = new List<FilesWrap>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdList = [SELECT ContentDocument.Title,ContentDocument.FileType,ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate , ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:objectId];
        for(ContentDocumentLink cd : cdList){
            if(cd.ContentDocument.FileType != 'SNOTE'){
                wrapList.add(new FilesWrap(cd));
            }
        }
        System.debug('---'+wrapList);
        return wrapList;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string deleteFiles(string objectId,string contentDocumentId){
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId=:contentDocumentId];
        try{
            if(cdlList.size() <= 2){
                delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :contentDocumentId];
            }else{
                delete [SELECT ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId=:objectId AND ContentDocumentId=:contentDocumentId];
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
        return 'Success';
    }
    public class FilesWrap{
        @AuraEnabled public String title;
        @AuraEnabled public String fileType;
        @AuraEnabled public String id;
        @AuraEnabled public DateTime lastModifiedDate;

        public FilesWrap(ContentDocumentLink cd){
            title = cd.ContentDocument.Title;
            id = cd.ContentDocumentId;
            fileType = cd.ContentDocument.FileType;
            lastModifiedDate= cd.ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

I am have tried many ways but either I am not getting any coverages or getting errors. Would love some helpful insight on how to create a test class for this. thank you.

---

I was looked at that link earlier and setup test class like this.

```
@IsTest
public class DeleteFilesCtrlTest
{
    static testMethod void DeleteFilesCtrl()
    {

        Account acct = new Account(Name='TEST_ACCT');
        insert acct;

        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
                Title = 'Penguins',
                PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
                VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
                IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion;
        List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

        //create ContentDocumentLink  record 
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = acct.id;
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
        cdl.shareType = 'V';
        insert cdl;

    }
}
```

but this gives 0% coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
@IsTest
public class DeleteFilesCtrlTest {
    @IsTest
    static void DeleteFilesCtrl() {

        Account acct = new Account(Name = 'TEST_ACCT');
        insert acct;

        Account acct1 = new Account(Name = 'TEST_ACCT1');
        insert acct1

        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
                Title = 'Penguins',
                PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
                VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
                IsMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert contentVersion;
        List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

        //create ContentDocumentLink  record
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = acct.Id;
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
        cdl.ShareType = 'V';
        insert cdl;

        ContentDocumentLink cd2 = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cd2.LinkedEntityId = acct1.Id;
        cd2.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
        cd2.ShareType = 'V';
        insert cd2;


        Test.startTest();
        SFDCOauthModel_CIO.getFiles(acct.Id);
        // CAlling second time to cover the if and else part.
        SFDCOauthModel_CIO.deleteFiles(acct.Id, documents[0].Id);
        SFDCOauthModel_CIO.deleteFiles(acct.Id, documents[0].Id);
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Also make sure to cover your exception part. And modify the code to bulkify your DML operations.

Also keep a assert statement to check where you are getting required output.

And i believe as you might be new to Salesforce please do some [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) on how to write a test class, so that it will help you in future.

Comment: Thank you, Nagendra for pointing me in the right direction. I am able to sort this out with the help of your code and able to add assert statements as well. thank you.